# Disambiguating this in inner functions

Tags: javascript

Inner functions sometimes need to refer to `this` of an outer function. Does JavaScript have a widely used idiom for such? I came up with a solution involving assigning `this` to another variable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'set', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function (a) {
        this.length = 0
        var this1 = this
        a.forEach(function (x) {
            this1.push(x)
        })
    }
})
```

But I'm not sure whether this is the cleanest or most idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use `that` as a variable name instead of `this1`, but other than that it's both clean, conventional and idiomatic Javascript.

[Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) also seems to recommend using `that`.

> By convention, we make a private that variable. This is used to make
>   the object available to the private methods. This is a workaround for
>   an error in the ECMAScript Language Specification which causes this to
>   be set incorrectly for inner functions.

In the past, I've also seen people using `self`.

Comment: I personally use `self` as it seems more descriptive to me than `that`, but it's obviously just a personal preference what name you like.  What's more important is to pick a convention and stick with it so your code is consistent.  If you're working in code other people wrote, use their convention to preserve the consistency.

Comment: @jfriend00 +1 Completely agree. Consistency is king.